# What should be expected from ODBC when a deadlock occurs?

Tags: sql-server, odbc

I'm executing sql on MS SQL 2008 using ODBC's SQLExecute().  My code calls a stored procedure which becomes a deadlock victim.  The server rollsback and the procedure is terminated, but SQLExecute() returns **success**.

The server trace logs clearly show the deadlock, but an ODBC trace has no sign of any problem.  The deadlocks are expected since there is a lot of concurrency going on, but my application can't recover unless its told there was a problem.

Should the ODBC driver return an error here?  The docs state that @@error should be set after a deadlock, but isn't it ODBC's responsibility to capture that info?

Answer (score 2):

Arrrg! Missing "set nocount on" inside a stored procedure.  No room in the buffer for the deadlock error with all the backed up row update counts.